# Is SetTimeout() for days a bad practice?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

So, my Meteor app lets users register for a free 14-day trial. When they register, their DB document is updated with 'Free Trial: Active'.

I'd like for the document to automatically update to 'Free Trial: Expired' after 14 days from the registration date, but was wondering if SetTimeout() with a 14-day delay (in ms) would be appropriate?

Comment: No, it won't be appropriate. You should have that check either at the server end or you should use a light weight api endpoint to get its expiry and update the UI accordingly.

Comment: What is this setTimeout for? Updating the DB? Then not by any mean, don't even let anything on your client side make this change. If it's only to display a message in the case they stay connected for 14 days? Then... that won't cost anything, and might even work.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's not the correct way of solving your problem.

You'll want to store a date of when their trial expires against their account, and check on login whether their trial has expired (i.e. is today's date > the expiration date?) displaying a message if it has.

Comment: You might want to capture the time too, considering a 14 day trial isn't exactly a 14 day trial if you end all trials at midnight no matter what time they started.
Also you might want them to check the date + time against your system and not their own since they could simply change the time

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to have a field in your database called something like `expiresAt` set for a date/time 14 days in the future. Whenever you authenticate by querying for the account, you'll want to run logic like this:

```sql
SELECT
  # yadda yadda yadda
FROM
  accounts
WHERE
  expiresAt > NOW()
```

The problem with something like `setTimeout` is that it's a runtime construct. So that means that it occupies processor and memory space while it's running. On top of that, you would lose the `setTimeout` process if the machine that it's running on was powered down or crashed, and you wouldn't be able to replicate that functionality across multiple machines or processes.

Comment: I was actually mainly concerned about whether it occupies processor and memory space while running, so thanks for your input

Comment: @CentoKili53 You're welcome. It of course is a negligible amount, but it would add up at any non-trivial amount of scale.

Comment: @CentoKili53 A timer does occupy a small amount of memory, but it does NOT use any CPU or any other system resource until it is its turn to run.  node.js is very, very efficient with timers and it stores them in a sorted linked list.  The event loop only checks if it's time for the next timer to run, it literally does not matter (from a performance point of view) how many additional timers there are in the list.  That said, you likely need a "durable" solution here that withstands a server restart so a timer alone would not suffice.